# TkInter messagebox bug Warning: Expected min height of view ?? (macOS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, visual-studio-code, macos-monterey

To start here is some background information:
Python Version 3.9.10 64bit
TkInter v8.6
macOS Monterey 12.3.1
Running from VS Code

In short I am trying to learn the TkInter module. Everything works well except when I try to use messagebox. It throws an error and so far I haven't found anything to help me out. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling a tkinter and macvim with no success. Please let me know what you guys find! (Error appears when initially running code and when initiate by the button)

Error Code:
**(base) rutemauro@Caios-Mac-Book cps121 %  cd /Users/rutemauro/Desktop/cps121 ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/rut
emauro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 54603 -- /Users/rutemauro/Desktop
/cps121/python-practice/TkInter-GUI/loginTemplate.py
2022-04-20 01:05:35.263 Python[2534:43780] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x7fc31191aab0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.
2022-04-20 01:05:36.342 Python[2534:43780] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x7fc311a59fe0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.**

Its a simple login form so here is the code that matters:

```
#Login Function
def loginFunc():
    if usernameEntry.get() == 0:
        messagebox.showerror("login unsuccessful", "Please Enter a Password")
    elif passwordEntry.get() == 0:
        messagebox.showerror("login unsuccessful", "Please Enter a Password")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("login successful", "You have successfully been logged in")


#Login Button
loginButton = Button(root, text="Login", font=("Arial",16), command=loginFunc)
loginButton.pack(pady=20)
```

github to full code (i think): https://gist.github.com/caiomauro/1abc39c5f2826d18e78555ec776df6b4